# recursive function with variable number of arguments - how to pass left arguments?

Tags: php, recursion

I have an array like this:

```
$months = Array ( 
"may" =>
    Array (
        "A" => 101,
        "B" => 33,
        "C" => 25
    ),
"june" =>
    Array (
        "A" => 73,
        "B" => 11,
        "D" => 32
    ),
"july" =>
    Array (
        "A" => 45,
        "C" => 12
    )
);
```

I want to get an array like this:

```
Array ( ['all'] => 
            Array (
           [A] => 219
           [B] => 44
           [C] => 37
           [D] => 32
          )
    )
```

I wrote a function with 2 parameters (the two arrays to join) and it worked, but I fail, when  I try to make it possible to call it with more than 2 arrays. I tried to do it via recursion:

```
function array_merge_elements(){
    $arg_list = func_get_args();
    $array1 = $arg_list[0];
    $array2 = $arg_list[1];
    $keys = array_unique(array_merge(array_keys($array1), array_keys($array2)));
    $result_array = array();
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        $result_array["$key"] = 0;
        if(!empty($array1[$key])) {
            $result_array["$key"] += $array1[$key];
        }
        if(!empty($array2[$key])) {
            $result_array["$key"] += $array2[$key];
        }
    }
    if(func_num_args() == 2) {
        return $result_array;
    } else {
        unset($arg_list[0]);
        unset($arg_list[1]);
        return array_merge_elements($result_array, $arg_list);
    }
}
```

The problem seems to be, that calling the function with (array1, arglist) is not the same as calling the function with (array1, array2, array3) etc.

Comment: why can't you declare function as `array_merge_elements($array1,$array2)`?

Comment: I can, but i wanted to be able to say array_merge_elements($array1,$array2, $array3) as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with just doing ([demo](http://codepad.org/DIF4bELg))

```
foreach ($months as $month) {
    foreach ($month as $letter => $value) {
        if (isset($months['all'][$letter])) {
            $months['all'][$letter] += $value;
        } else {
            $months['all'][$letter] = $value;
        }
    }
}
print_r($months['all']);
```

or - somewhat less readable due to the ternary operation ([demo](http://codepad.org/PtN7gCHc)):

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($months));
foreach ($iterator as $letter => $value) {
    isset($months['all'][$letter])
        ? $months['all'][$letter] += $value
        : $months['all'][$letter] = $value;
}
print_r($months['all']);
```

Comment: Recursion is not the way to solve the problem. BTW the if...else... construct is redundant - just using '$months['all'][$letter] += $value;' would suffice (although it will generate warnings)

Comment: @symcbean Recursive Iterators are fine for this problem. Also, if the += code raises Notices (which it does), it isnt redundant to check for that condition.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd split off the first two entries of your found arguments; you can use the resulting array in a call with this function: [Call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/function.call-user-func-array.php)

Answer (score 0):

for fellow googlers out there, here's the answer to the *original* question

Assume we have a function that adds two arrays together:

```
function array_plus($a, $b) {
    foreach($b as $k => $v)
        $a[$k] = (isset($a[$k]) ? $a[$k] : 0) + $v;
    return $a;
}
```

this is how to apply this function to a set of arrays

```
$sum = array_reduce($months, 'array_plus', array());
```